# Имеется список, состоящий из 0 и 1. Как найти длину самой длинной подпоследовательности стоящих подряд одинаковых элементов?

Tags: python

```
data = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

max_length = 1
current_max_length = 1

for i in range(len(data)):
    if i == data[i-1]:
        current_max_length += 1
    if i !=data[i-1]:
        max_length == current_max_length 
        current_max_length = 1
    
    if current_max_length > max_length:
        max_length = current_max_length
```

Comment: Для чего сравнивается индекс элемента массива со значением элемента массива? `if i == data[i-1]:`

Answer (score 3):

##### [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
import itertools


data = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

print(max(sum(1 for _ in g) for _, g in itertools.groupby(data)))
```

`itertools.groupby(data)` возвращает последовательность групп одинаковых элементов:

> ```
> значение    группа
> 0           [0]
> 1           [1, 1, 1]
> 0           [0]
> 1           [1]
> 0           [0, 0]
> 1           [1]
> 0           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
> 1           [1]
> ```

Значения нам не интересны - поэтому в коде есть `_`. У каждой группы `g` измеряется длина. Группа возвращается не целиком как список, а как итератор. `sum(1 for _ in g)` буквально считает сколько раз итератор сработает до исчерпания группы.

`max` выбирает максимальное значение.

##### Без библиотек

... задачу можно решить так:

```
data = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

max_length = 0
length_ending_here = 0

prev = 0
for v in data:
    if v == prev:
        length_ending_here += 1
    else:
        length_ending_here = 1

    if length_ending_here > max_length: 
        max_length = length_ending_here

    prev = v

print(max_length)
```

Отличия от вашего кода:

- переменные первоначально устанавливаются в ноль. Это нужно для правильной обработки пустого списка `data`;
- предыдущее значение запоминается в `prev`. Начальное значение может быть любое;
- цикл делается по значениям. Индексы не нужны, они только запутывают.

Отличий не так много.

Этот код можно ещё немного ускорить. Не буду этого делать - текущий код простой, а это важно чтобы убедится в его правильности.

Answer (score 0):

Вот программа. Первое `data =`  - любой список из `0` и `1`. Нужно только в конец сразу добавить что угодно кроме `0` или `1` (что и делает `.append()`), чтоб прервать конечную последовательность.

```
data = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]

data.append(2)

maximum = 0
zero_maximum = 0
one_maximum = 0
flag = 1

for k in range(len(data)):
    if flag == 1:
        if data[k] == 1:
            one_maximum += 1
        else:
            if one_maximum > maximum:
                maximum = one_maximum
            one_maximum = 0
            flag = 0
    elif flag == 0:
        if data[k] == 0:
            zero_maximum += 1
        else:
            if zero_maximum > maximum:
                maximum = zero_maximum
            zero_maximum = 0
            flag = 0

print(maximum)
```

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, исправил.

Answer (score 0):

Универсальный вариант. Подсчитывает для всех элементов списка: и для 0, и для 1 и т.д. Позволяет выполнять другие расчеты, не только max.

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict

# в конец списка добавил несколько "инородных" элементов исключительно для демонстрации возможностей
data = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 'a', 'a', 'a']

keys_lst = list() #список сгруппированных элементов
len_lst = list() #список количеств повторяющихся элементов
keys_lst = [str(k) for k, _ in groupby(data)] #для единообразия все ключи строковые
len_lst = [len(list(g)) for _, g in groupby(data)] #вычисляем размер группы

dict_full = defaultdict(list) #словарь, в который соберем вместе элементы и их количество повторов по группам
for k, v in zip(keys_lst, len_lst):
    dict_full[k].append(v)
#Выводим для примера варианты подсчетов. Тут можно еще пофантазировать
for k in dict_full.keys():
    print(f'Min for {k}: {min(dict_full[k])}')
    print(f'Max for {k}: {max(dict_full[k])}')
    print(f'Total for {k}: {sum(dict_full[k])}')
    print(f'Counter for {k}: {len(dict_full[k])}')
```

Для удобства облачим в функцию:

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import Union

def Counting_List(
    data_list: list, #список с данными
    key_name: str = None, #элемент, для которого нужно выполнить подсчет
    result_name: str = "Total", #какой именно нужен подсчет
) -> Union[int, float, None]: #на всякий случай добавлен float
    keys_lst = list()
    len_lst = list()
    dict_full = defaultdict(list)
    #словарь, в котором задаем функции для подсчета различных значений
    # если элемент (ключ key_name) не найден, вернет 0
    dict_results = dict() 
    dict_results = {
        "total": lambda: sum(dict_full.get(key_name, [0])),
        "min": lambda: min(dict_full.get(key_name, [0])),
        "max": lambda: max(dict_full.get(key_name, [0])),
    }

    keys_lst = [str(k) for k, _ in groupby(data_list)]
    len_lst = [len(list(g)) for _, g in groupby(data_list)]
    for k, v in zip(keys_lst, len_lst):
       dict_full[k].append(v)
    # переводим в нижний регистр для исключения ошибок написания
    # если метод подсчета не удалось распознать, то возвращаем None (можно заменить на 0)
    return dict_results.get(result_name.lower(), lambda: None)()
```

Оба варианта позволяют выполнять разновариантные подсчеты для практически любых элементов списка не зависимо от их количества. В качестве побочного эффекта можно подсчитать количество символов в строке, хотя для этого удобнее использовать другие методы.